# How to create a Remember Me token and write it to the user's cookies after registration using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

User registration logic:

```
    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public String registerUser(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> formData, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
        logger.info("REGISTER USER");
        String username = formData.getFirst("username");
        String password = formData.getFirst("password");
        String passwordConfirm = formData.getFirst("password-confirm");
        if (userRepository.findByUsername(username) != null) {
            logger.info("UNSUCCESSFUL: username already taken");
            model.addAttribute("usernameAlreadyTaken", true);
            return "register";
        }
        if (!password.equals(passwordConfirm)) {
            logger.info("UNSUCCESSFUL: passwords don't match");
            model.addAttribute("passwordMismatch", true);
            return "register";
        }
        // save user to database
        User newUser = new User(0L, username, password);
        userRepository.save(newUser);
        roleRepository.save(new Role(0L, newUser, "USER"));
        // remember user
        Authentication formAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(formAuth);
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
        rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        // invalidate session - prevent session fixation attacks
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        securityContextRepository.saveContext(securityContext, request, response);
        logger.info("SUCCESSFUL: new user created");
        return "register";
    }
```

I want that after a user registers, a Remember Me token is created for him to remember the user.

I use this method:

```
rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, authentication);
```

The user registration is successful, but after restarting the application I have to log into the site again, although this should not be the case, since in theory I have already created the corresponding Remember Me token for this user to automatically log into the site. What went wrong and how to fix it?

My security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filter(HttpSecurity http, SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository, CustomAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler,
                                      CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler, RememberMeServices rememberMeServices) throws Exception {
        return http
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenLogger(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/user").hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/admin").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form.loginPage("/login").failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler).securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository))
                .logout((logout) -> logout.logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID"))
                .rememberMe((remember) -> remember.rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices))
                .securityContext(securityContext -> securityContext.securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository))
                .exceptionHandling((exception) -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")).accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RememberMeServices rememberMeServices(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        TokenBasedRememberMeServices.RememberMeTokenAlgorithm encodingAlgorithm = TokenBasedRememberMeServices.RememberMeTokenAlgorithm.SHA256;
        TokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMe = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("secretKeyForRememberMeToken", userDetailsService, encodingAlgorithm);
        rememberMe.setMatchingAlgorithm(TokenBasedRememberMeServices.RememberMeTokenAlgorithm.MD5);
        return rememberMe;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
        return new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
                new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

I didn’t find a tutorial on the Internet on how to remember a user after registration using the Remember Me token